# Update brand logos via AccountBrands:update from API

Tags: docusignapi

Currently in my app, I create a brand if there is none (with just brand company and brand name).

Then I update it when I update some settings. It updates colors and logos.

In the documentation of the method [AccountBrands:update](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Accounts/AccountBrands/update), there is a brandLogos definition that says that the method accepts 3 parameters : email, primary and secondary. And for each, the value must be a string.

My problem is that I don't know what to put in these strings.
I tried with the public URL of the image, the binary data of the image and the base 64 encoded binary data of the image, but nothing works.

Does anyone know how it works ?

Comment: It's challenging to add an image in one single string so I am not sure how. I have had similar issues with the generic API reference documentation. You might be able to do a separate multipart call and add the images but not so clean.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question directly, but you can create the brand without logos, get the Brand ID in the response, and then use the [AccountBrands:updateLogo](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Accounts/AccountBrands/updateLogo) method to add the logos after the fact. UpdateLogo takes the binary data in the body.

Comment: Yeah I tried to do that with Postman, I called the URL {{baseUrl}}/brands/{{brandId}}/logos/primary with binary body type containing the image I want to send.

I had no error in the response body but the brand still have no images :/